# Stacking of several Surface plots in 3D-View

Tags: r, plot, 3d, surface

Lets consider that I have five 2D-Matrices which describe the magnetic field at different z-Layers. A nice, smoothed version of a 2D-Surface plot can be obtained as follows:

```
data2_I<-matrix(c(1.0,1.0,0.6,0.6,0.7,0.9,0.9,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.7,0.9,0.9,0.6,0.3,0.4,0.7,0.9,0.9,0.7,0.5,0.5,0.6,0.9,0.9,0.7,0.6,0.6,1.0,1.0), nrow=5)
Z = as.vector(data2_I)
length(Z)
XY=data.frame(x=as.numeric(gl(5,1,30)),y=as.numeric(gl(5,6,30)))
t=Tps(XY,Z)
surface(t)
```

Now it would be great if I could get a 3D-plot where at different z-Positions these surfaces are plotted. Is there a possibility to do that?

Comment: You should include the `library` call relevant to `Tps`. Also, this example is not reproducible - people are much more likely to help you if you give us a self-contained example (we don't have `data2_I`).

Comment: Ups, sorry, I forgot to include this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative approach: With the package rgl I and the function surface 3D I can stack several 3D-Surface plots within one open3d-window. Lets look at a small example:

```
library("rgl")
data2_I<-matrix(c(1.0,1.0,0.6,0.6,0.7,0.9,0.9,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.7,0.9,0.9,0.6,0.3,0.4,0.7,0.9,0.9,0.7,0.5,0.5,0.6,0.9,0.9,0.7,0.6,0.6,1.0,1.0), nrow=5)
data0_I<-matrix(c(1.0,1.0,0.6,0.6,0.7,0.9,0.9,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.7,0.9,0.9,0.6,0.3,0.4,0.7,0.9,0.9,0.7,0.5,0.5,0.6,0.9,0.9,0.7,0.6,0.6,1.0,1.0), nrow=5)
data1_I<-2*data0_I
data2_I<-1/data1_I

elv=0
offs=5*elv+1
z0 <- scale*data0_I        
z1 <- scale*data1_I
z2 <- scale*data2_I
x <- 1:nrow(z0)   
y <- 1:ncol(z0)   

palette <- colorRampPalette(c("blue","green","yellow", "red")) 
col.table <- palette(256)
open3d(windowRect=c(50,50,800,800))
surface3d(x, y, elv*z0, color = col.table[cut(z0, 256)], back = "lines") 
surface3d(x, y, elv*z1+1*offs, color = col.table[cut(z1, 256)], back = "lines")
surface3d(x, y, elv*z2+2*offs, color = col.table[cut(z2, 256)], back = "lines")
axes3d()
aspect3d(1,1,2)
```

The variables offsand elv are included for cosmetic purposes: offs controls the space between two surface plots and elevation how the z-axes of the surface3d-plots should scale. As I wanted to have a 2D surface plot without any elevation I set it to zero.